# Firebase load data before Vue created

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, html-framework-7

```
<template>
  <f7-page>
    <f7-navbar>
        <f7-nav-left back-link="Zurück"></f7-nav-left>
        <f7-nav-right></f7-nav-right>
    </f7-navbar>
    <f7-list>
        <f7-list-item>{{this.test.testKey}}</f7-list-item>
    </f7-list>
    <!-- <f7-list v-for="email in this.test.data">
        <f7-list-item>{{email.email}}</f7-list-item>
    </f7-list> -->
    <pre>
        <p>{{this.test}}</p>
    </pre>
  </f7-page>
</template>
<script>
import *  as firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
    beforeCreate() {
        var this_ = this
        firebase.firestore().collection("tests").doc(this_.$f7route.params.testKey).onSnapshot({
        }, function(doc) {
            this_.test = ({data: doc.data()})
        })

        console.log(this.test)

    },
    data() {
        return {
            test: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

My Problem is that as it seems firebase is not defined when the view gots load. The Pre does work but the Information is now shown in the list elements. I really dont know why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Use created instead of beforeCreate, before the vue instance is created, the data (and subsequently 'test') object doesn't exist. Refer to the lifecycle hooks documentation at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks